# How can I log scraping error and move on without halting script

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using python and beautifulsoup to scrape a site. My script always stop when it get to a certain url and states

> > > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

i forsee this happening in other areas of the site too. what I want is log the error and the url that created it and then continue without halting my script. 
I have tried this

```
  uClient2 = ''
  try:
     uClient2 = requests.get(FSGsubcardref)
     print("Proceding to get the sub_subblink...")
  except Exception as error:
      logger.exception(error)
      print("Connection refused by the server..")
      time.sleep(8)
      continue
```

it does not halt when connection is lost anymore but it still stops for attribute error. How can I just log the error and continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the places where you expect Exceptions to occur.  In your code above, you are catching Exceptions in connecting to the site and retrieving the page.  The `AttributeError` you mention happens after you have successfully retrieved the page.  So you must have some code that does the bs4 parsing.  There is where you need to catch the Exception:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
try:
    tags = soup.find_all()
    # whatever else you do
except AttributeError as e:
    logger.error(e)
```

Comment: ok. Can I make this applicable to any error found during the bs4 parsing. so that it will not be for attribute error alone?

Comment: Sure, you can catch `Exception` if you want.  In general, it's better to catch specific errors and have routines that handle them, but catching the general `Exception` is fine to start.